# Azure Function default authorization key changing on publish

Tags: git, azure, azure-functions

Is this intended? We had an Azure function that we had running and setup our connection to it with the default function key since we specified function level authorization and everything was working great. We also setup CD on this function with it syncing to a github repo on the master branch. We just found out this morning that when we pushed some new changes to master last night and it built that our connection broke. When we looked back at the function key it was different than when we had originally configured it.

So my question is this. Does the generated default function key get automatically renewed when you publish new changes to a function? Is that intended behavior? And if so, what do you do to keep a stable connection for your clients even when updates are made to these kinds of functions?

Or is this potentially just an issue with CD?

Comment: This is definitely not intended behavior, and is likely a bug in the product. We are investigating. But it is probably not directly related to publishing.

Comment: Could it be you're removing the function in the CD before publishing it?

Comment: How are you removing the Function? Deleting a Function does cause everything about it to be deleted.

Comment: @DavidEbbo We are just using the github continuous integration setup and aren't deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue around keys getting deleted, and a new Functions Runtime (version 1.0.11380) was deployed on Monday to address the issue.